# how to call javascript in webview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am beginner of iPhone. I want to call javascript page in webview. I have used script like

```
    <script src="http://www.infochoice.com.au/modules/applets/flash9/Source/Scripts/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <div id="ich_flashcontent"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               var ich_calc_detect = new SWFObject("http://www.infochoice.com.au/modules/applets/flash9/Source/Applets/600/LoanRepayments.swf", "ich_LoanRepayments", "595", "330", "9", "#000");
               ich_calc_detect.addVariable("splash_location", "http://www.infochoice.com.au/modules/applets/flash9/Source/Applets/splash_icon.swf");
               ich_calc_detect.addVariable("info_location", "http://www.infochoice.com.au/distributions/flash9/58/info/");
               ich_calc_detect.addVariable("xml_location", "http://www.infochoice.com.au/distributions/flash9/58/");
               ich_calc_detect.addVariable("core_location", "http://www.infochoice.com.au/modules/applets/flash9/Source/Applets/StGeorge/");
               ich_calc_detect.addParam("AllowScriptAccess", "always");
               ich_calc_detect.addParam("wmode", "transparent"); 
               ich_calc_detect.useExpressInstall('http://www.infochoice.com.au/modules/applets/flash9/Source/Applets/expressinstall.swf');
               ich_calc_detect.write("ich_flashcontent");
            </script>
```

Please give any suggestion and source code which is apply in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:%your javascript string%];
```

Note 10 sec for execution and 10mb of ram per this call or it will be killed no matter if it finished execution or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your_javascript_here"];`

Comment: we used this method to communicate between the native part of the app and the javascript inside a webview. I'd encapsulate your javascript in a function and call the function from the app via the suggested method.

Answer (score 0):

I've executed java script for UIWebview in the following way

```
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%f%%'",(fontSize * 10.0)];
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
  [jsString release];
```

Hope it may help you. Here self is an instance of UIWebView.